# Dispersion of mid-air particles: scaling laws and similarity solutions of a function

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics, applications

I'm currently looking at some old questions from my undergraduate studies which I may not have fully understood but would like to understand now.

The initial stage of a dispersal process is very complicated. However, after a time scale of order $h^{2}/k$, the concentration profile in the vertical direction will settle down; for simplicity, assume that for this preliminary model, the concentration is independent of z, so $c(x,y,z,t) = c(x,y,t)$ and that the fall -out is negligible.

Under the prescribed circumstance, c(x,y,z)=c(r,t)
where

> $r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$

so that it's appropriate to use cylindrical form of the Laplacian and the dispersal is governed by

> $\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}=k\left ( \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial r^2} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial c}{\partial r}\right )$
>
> Question: Use scaling arguments to show that the similarity solution form is given by

$c\left ( r,t \right )=\frac{M}{kht}C\left ( \xi \right )$

I am unfamiliar with scaling arguments. A good explanation to the above question would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is the meaning of $h, M, C, \xi$.